# Buy more lottery tickets or more multipliers?

Tags: probability

In a given lottery, let's say my odds of winning a grand prize are $p_0$, and the grand prize has value $V$. I can either buy more tickets, at a cost $C_1$, or for each ticket, I can buy a multiplier for each ticket, at a cost $C_2$ per ticket. The multipliers are structured as follows:

```
5X      
1 in 10
4X  
1 in 10
3X  
1 in 3.33
2X  
1 in 2
```

That is, if I pay $C_2$ extra for a ticket for a multiplier, then I have a $1/2$ chance of doubling my prize, a $1/3$ chance of tripling, etc.

For simplicity let's assume there is only the grand prize of value $V$. Should I buy more tickets, or buy multipliers on all my tickets?

### My Thoughts

My average payout per ticket is $Vp_0$, which costs $C_1N$, if I buy $N$ tickets. So if I buy multipliers on $M \leq N$ tickets, my profit equation takes the form: 
$$
\text{Profit} = NVp_0 - C_1N - C_2M
$$ 
I suppose the question is, at what point does the incremental payout from an additional ticket become less than buying a multiplier on an existing ticket. If $m$ is the multiplier, and $P_m$ is the probability of that multiplier, then the question is at what point does $Vp_0 - C_1 \lessgtr mP_mVp_0 - C_2$

Comment: Your chance of tripling is $\frac 3{10}$, not $\frac 13$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I play the lottery with a specific amount of money, should I put it all on one game or distribute it among several games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990504/if-i-play-the-lottery-with-a-specific-amount-of-money-should-i-put-it-all-on-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the assumption that there are lots of tickets sold (so your buying one more does not change the value of the existing tickets), each ticket has some expected value $v$.  This includes all the prizes.  If you buy another ticket, you get $v$.  If you buy a multiplier, you get $v(\frac 12 \cdot 1 + \frac 3{10}\cdot 2 + \frac 1{10}\cdot 3 + \frac 1{10}\cdot 4)=\frac {18}{10}v$ added to your value.  Your loss on buying another ticket is $C_1-v.$  Your loss on buying a multiplier is $C_2-\frac {18}{10}v.$  Compare these and you will know which way you are less badly off.

Comment: Actually I double with chance $1$ in $2$ so isn't it ($1/2 \cdot 2 + 1/3 \cdot 3 + \cdots$)? But thank you this is the way I was thinking about it

Comment: No, because you were already getting $v$.  When you double, your increase is $v$, so that is the value of the multiplier.